# Is wglShareLists transitive? Do I have to share each context with the other?

Tags: windows, opengl, wgl

For example, if I share render context 'A' with render context 'B', then share render context 'C' with 'A', will 'C' be shared with 'B'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, wglShareLists is transitive.